# A* Algorithm seems to run in circles, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, a-star

I have written a a star algorithm for a game I am making (first time I ever used it) and it is unable to find any target that is more than one tile away. I used the debugger to see what was going on and it did seem somewhat like it was running in circles. Here is my algorithm (sx,sy are the start tile coordinates and tx,ty are the target coordinates. Also this function is part of a class incase you where wondering about the undefined variables):

```
void Pathfinder(int sx, int sy, unsigned int tx, unsigned int ty, int map[7][11],std::map<array2,Door*> doors,int dv){
                if (!map[ty][tx] == 0){ return;}
                Node map_nodes [7][11];

                std::vector<Node*> open;
                int current_index, x, y, tile;
                path.clear();

                map_nodes[sy][sx].load(sx,sy,tx,ty,0, true, false,0,0);

                Node* current = &map_nodes[sy][sx];
                open.push_back(current);

                while (open.size() > 0) {
                    for (int b = 0; b < open.size(); ++b) {
                        if (b == 0 || open[b]->f < current->f) {
                            current = open[b];
                            current_index = b;
                        }
                    }
                    // checks if current is the target
                    if (current->x == tx && current->y == ty) {
                        int path_length = current->g + 1;
                        path.resize(path_length, {0, 0});

                        for (int p = 0; p < path_length; p++) {
                            path[p][0] = current->x;
                            path[p][1] = current->y;
                            current = &map_nodes[current->y][current->x];
                        }
                        return;
                    }

                    current->closed = true;
                    current->open = false;
                    open.erase(open.begin() + current_index);

                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                        for (int u = 0; u < 3; u++) {
                            if (k != 1 && u != 1) {
                                x = current->x + u - 1;
                                y = current->y + k - 1;
                                if (x >= 0 && y >= 0) {
                                    //checks if it is traversable
                                    if (map_nodes[y][x].closed || (map[y][x] == 0 || (map[y][x] >= dv && doors[{x, y}]->access_level <= acess_level))) {
                                        if (!map_nodes[y][x].open) {
                                            map_nodes[y][x].load(x, y, tx, ty, current->g + 1, true, false, current->x,current->y);
                                            open.push_back(&map_nodes[y][x]);
                                        } else if (current->g < map_nodes[y][x].g) {
                                            map_nodes[y][x].update_f(current->g, current->x,current->y);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And here is the node class:

```
class Node{
    public:
        int x = 0, y = 0, f = 0, g = 0, h = 0, px = 0, py = 0;
        bool open = false, closed = false;
        void load(int xa, int ya, int tx, int ty, unsigned int ga, bool opena, bool closeda, int pxa,int pya){
            x = xa;
            y = ya;

            g = ga;
            h = ((tx - x) * (tx - x)) + ((ty - y) * (ty - y));

            f = g + h;

            open = opena;
            closed = closeda;

            px = pxa;
            py = pya;
        }
        void update_f(unsigned int ga, int pxa, int pya){
            g = ga;
            f = g + h;
            px = pxa;
            py = pya;
        }
    };
```

**EDIT:**
Never mind fixed it, had one of the if commands where missing a ! which messed the whole thing up.

Comment: Each node should be added to the queue exactly once. Sounds like your code can put a given node into the queue multiple times.

Comment: How are you weeding out visited nodes (i.e., making sure you're not adding them back to `open` again)?

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry I took down the question because I noticed a issue with my code and first wanted to fix it. Though if you have a answer thank you soo much!

Comment: @Yunnosch I will but I don’t have much time right now so I am not sure when that will be since I did some big mistakes. Again I have very little experience with this.

Comment: Take your time, you are going the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Start with some A* pseudo code, [such as this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode) on wikipedia.  (Wikipedia is a decent source of pseudo code for famous algorithms, as enough random people drive by and fix the worst typos)

Transcribe it into comments.  Now, leaving the comments, write it line by line.

Simply dumping a pile of not working code and asking "what am I doing wrong" requires someone to first figure out what each line of your code is *trying* to do (without assuming it is doing something reasonable), then map that to the implementation of A* they are used to, determine what you are doing that actually leads to the problem you are seeing.

With comments adjacent to each line saying what it is *supposed* to do, the problem of finding a bug becomes O(n) easier; you can spot a single line that fails to do what that comments say, or you can spot an error in the comments.

TL;DR what "you are doing wrong" is writing an algorithm out using low level C style programming and no connection back to a formally correct version of the algorithm, and expecting it to work.

In general when writing algorithms important enough to have a name, you'll want to be able to refer back to the pseudo-code description of what you are supposed to be doing.  Simply writing code that "does what you think it should" makes it much, much harder to track down problems.

This may not line up with the sample code you find implementing such algorithms; sometimes this is because the person writing the sample code has implemented that algorithm dozens of times, other times because they have removed the comments (either afterwards, or as they wrote the code), or because they where confident (and lucky enough) to do it right the first time.